# Running OpenVZ virtual servers within a Xen XCP vritual server? Bad practice?

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, openvz

I have a 1 server with 8GB RAM and 2xQuadcore Processors. It currently has the Xen XCP installed on it, and centos6.2 x64 running on a virtual machine.

I have a server control panel software that I want to use and it allows the administration via a web interface for Openvz machines.

My questions are:

1. Would this be considered bad practice?
2. Would there be a big performance hit?
3. Should I avoid this all together or am I going about it all wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVZ is "chroot() on steroids" — virtualization through better processes isolation, so it should be absolutely okay to run OVZ inside XEN.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply back. The control panel I was considering using was ISPconfig3 but on their forums they told me that you should never run a virtual machine inside of a virtual machine. I am new to virtualization and just wanted to make sure whether or not I was going about it the right way.

Comment: How many times should you be told that OVZ is different kind of virtualization? ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization

Comment: 1 time I believe?? Thank you for the link, definitely cleared up a lot :).

Comment: Also make sure you give lxc a try.